# Не работает плагин gulp-sass-glob

Tags: npm, плагин, gulp4

Всем привет! Для компиляции SCSS использую Gulp (v.4). Хочу импортировать все _.scss файлы в main.scss при помощи плагина gulp-sass-glob, который установил по описанию плагина. Однако при создании соответствующей переменной (sassGlob) в gulpfile имя этой переменной подсвечивается так, будто данный плагин не установлен. Соответственно, ничего не работает. С чем это может быть связано и как это пофиксить?

[image: Скрин из редактора]

```
const
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass')),
    sassGlob = require('gulp-sass-glob');

function scssTask() {
    return gulp.src('scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sassGlob())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
}

const watchFiles = () => {
    gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss'], gulp.series(scssTask));
}

const start = gulp.series(scssTask);

exports.default = gulp.parallel(start, watchFiles);
```

Comment: Приложите текстом код на всякий случай

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. В отличие от описания на странице плагина, в начале пути к просматриваемым папкам нужно было поставить "./"  и всё заработало. Цвет переменной в редакторе к данной проблеме отношения не имеет.